# SQL Server 2008 - toggle value in table, based on children values. Triggers or computed column with sub query?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following tables

**Parent Table**

```
ds_id(pk)   / state
-------------------------
        1.       /    valid
        2.       /    invalid
```

**Child Table**

```
d_id(pk)  /   ds_id(fk)  /  approve
-----------------------------------------
  1.     /       1.        /       false
  2.     /       1.        /       true
  3.     /       2.        /       false
  4.     /       2.        /       false
```

The `state` column in the parent table should change to valid if one of its children in the child  table has its approved column set to true

I want to find the simplest most efficient method for calculating  and setting the state column based on its children.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

The change of state would need to be instant.

It is expected that the system would have a few thousand parents, each with around 5 children.

It is more likely that the children would be updated

Comment: Essentially you want parentTable.IsValid = Max(childTable.approve) (returning true if any of the child's is true). What's the value then of storing the is valid flag in the parent table and maintaining that relationship? Would it not be better to compute the state of the parent table from within the code of your application, or returning it via a stored proceedure?

Comment: I'd never considered not storing the value, thanks for pointing out the possibility. But that would require me to calculate the state each time I wanted to work with it. For example hiding a button based on state.

Comment: @MitchellLee: Valid, but depends on the logic and how to implement.  That's how I first model things, but model for stored values -- test & compare performance to decide.  Revisit the issue when there's actual client data...  Sometimes storing the value works better.

Comment: @OMGPonies I agree, although I usually take the opposite approach, I generally try to keep as much logic out of my database as physically possible, opting to change that only when performance demands. It's difficult to version control databases vs code, so if I can keep logic in the code it's easier to maintain.

Comment: @MitchellLee: Version for which DB?  My work with Oracle & CVS was pretty good (though somewhat manual); SQL Server and the DBDude/VStudio/SVN combination works but leaves a little to be desired (materialized/indexed view support, CLR, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided enough information to decide on what the "best" method is.  The two basic ideas are updating the data in the parent when a child value changes or summarizing from the children at query time.

Here are some questions to decide between these approaches:

What is the ratio of reads at the parent level to changes on the child level?  If the parent value would be read once for every thousand times that the child values change, then it is probably more efficient to do it dynamically (at query time).  If the parent value is read one thousand times for each time a child value changes, then it is probably more efficient to do it statically (with an update).

What are the expected response times for changing a child and reading from a parent?

How much data are we talking about?  If the child data is measured in hundreds of rows, it is probably not worth the effort to make the query more efficient.

And, the proposed data is a little awkward for automatic updating.  If a child changes from approved = true to false, then what happens?  You have to read all the other children in order to set the value in the parent.  The alternative is to keep a count of the approved children, and then do logic on that value.  One way to do that would be with a computed column in the parent table:

```
create table . . .
    stats as (case when ApprovedCount > 0 then valid else invalid end)
```

As a general observation for the automatic updates, I think triggers are relatively hard to maintain.  Using triggers does not seem "simple".  Instead, I would have a stored procedure for updating the child table and use the stored procedure for the update and any additional logic.

[Responding to the comments]
The data being suggested is quite small.  In all probability, the children and the parents will each fit on one data page.  Unless you are going for transaction processing benchmarks, you can do the computation on the fly when you query the parents:

```
select p.id, (case when count(*) > 0 then valid else invalid end) as validness
from parent p left outer join
     child c
     on c.parentid = p.parentid and c.accepted = true
group by p.id
```

This will go really fast.  And, if you are looking for only one parent at a time, it will be really, really fast.  Of course, it would be a small amount faster if you pre-calculated the value.  However, the increase in speed is highly unlikely to be important, relative to the complexity of maintaining the value.

Comment: The response time would need to be instant in this case. Also it is thought that each parent would have around 5 children on average and the children are more likely to be updated

Comment: In the few hundred range, with each child only having one parent